# Test a property only if it exists?

Tags: javascript

The following test generates an error if the response does not have a `msgs[0]` property.

```
if response.msgs[0] === "published" { ... }
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

How can I rewrite the test to generate an error? If there is no `msgs[0]` property, I want the test to evaluate to `false`.

Comment: `response.hasOwnProperty('msgs')`

Comment: @Rayon — That will return `true` even if the value is `undefined`, in which case accessing `[0]` will still throw the error quoted in the question.

Comment: @Quentin, True! `False` only if key does not exist at all :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> response does not have a msgs[0] property

This is incorrect. It throws an error because it doesn't have a `msgs` property, not because there is no `0` property on it.

You need to test if `msgs` exists before testing what `0` is.

```
if (response.msgs && response.msgs[0] === "published") { ... }
```

Comment: Even if `msgs` is defined, `msgs[0]` will still produce an error (`Unexpected end of input`) if `[0]` is not available.

Answer (score 3):

Test if `response.msgs` is defined first:

```
if response.msgs && response.msgs[0] === "published" { ... }
```